# Расположить иконку закрытия над картинкой

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Использую `Bootstrap 4`, в верстке не сильно шарю. Как расположить кнопку закрытия (та, что внутри `.close-image-icon`) в правом верхнем углу картинки, то есть по сути над ней?

```
<div>
  <span class="close-image-icon">
  <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
   <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
  </span>
  <img class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" :src="src" />
  <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mt-1" placeholder="Описание" v-model="description" @change="sendDescription" />
</div>
```

И попутно еще один вопрос: в обычном состоянии этот "крестик" должен быть спрятан, но при наведении мыши на картинку его надо активировать. Как это реализоваться среедствамии `CSS`? Не хочу для этого `JS` использовать. Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы указать абсолютное позиционирование крестика надо указать родительскому блоку стиль `position: relative`, чтобы не выходить за его рамки.

```css
.container>div {
  position: relative;
  /* Чтобы .close не выходил за рамки .container */
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  /* Ставим крестик справа */
}

.close-image-icon {
  display: none;
  /* Скрываем крестик по умолчанию */
}

.container>div:hover .close-image-icon {
  display: block !important;
  /* При навидении на div в .container показать крестик */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div>
    <span class="close-image-icon">
      <button type="button" class="close m-4" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    </span>
    <img class="img-thumbnail img-fluid w-100" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/fcc/000 ">
    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mt-1 " placeholder="Описание ">
  </div>
</div>
```